# How to display pretty tables in terminal with tabulate python package?

Tags: python, dataframe, terminal, argparse, tabulate

I am have simple CLI app written in python with argparse module. Basically I am fetching some cryptocurrency data with external api, I transform it into pandas dataframe and print it with tabulate module. But I have issue with printing tables in my terminal. When I am doing that everything goes wrong and the tables do not maintain the proper structure and in the end all looks like on screen belowe.

[image: Bad formatting]

Here is snippet for printing pandas data frame with tabulate

```
# file: example.py
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate


def get_recommendations():
    url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/recommended/all"
    req = requests.get(url, params={'fsym' : 'BTC' ,"tsym": 'USD'})
    return pd.DataFrame(req.json()['Data']['exchanges']).T


df = get_recommendations()

print(
    tabulate(
        df,
        headers=df.columns,
        floatfmt=".5f",
        showindex=True,
        tablefmt="psql",
    )
)
```

if you run in terminal
`python example.py` you will see mess in terminal like on screenshot above code snippet.

Can I some how fix it, and display nice, well formatted tables in my terminal like below ?
[image]

Comment: It looks like the table is wider than your terminal, do you have an example snippet of the data to make this a [mcve]?

Comment: Try [termtables](https://github.com/nschloe/termtables),   a lightweight Python 3 package for pretty-printing tables on the command line

Comment: @Alex I added full example. Hope that it is enough to recreate this.

Comment: @Pluviophile I will try to use this package, but I think maybe it's possible to somehowe add some constraints for terminal to display all in proper form, even if table has bigger size then terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar issue: How best to print out tables in the   Terminal? There are lots of different approaches (Of course, you can always just use PrettyPrinter). I found that if I use a  pandas DataFrame, combined with the [rich-dataframe](https://pypi.org/project/rich-dataframe/) module, I  can produce a decent-looking table in the Terminal.  So the code might look like this:

Suppose you start with a list. Convert the list to a dict. Then pass the dict to the dataframe. Finally, call the print statement at the end. It works fine in a Terminal.

Edit: In your MWE, you may need to convert the JSON object to a Python dict. Use `import json`, then `json.loads(dict)`
See [examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-json-to-dictionary-in-python/)

```
from rich_dataframe import prettify
import pandas as pd

languages = ['English', 'Italiano', 'Espanol']

x = dict(enumerate(languages))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, orient='index', columns=['Languages Supported'])

table = prettify(df, row_limit=10)

print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has the `DataFrame.to_markdown()` method, which uses tabulate to generate nice tables that you can print to the console. You can pass the `tablefmt=` parameter to get different style tables as per tabulate documentation.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html